# Customize TextInputLayout with hint inside TextInputEditText

Tags: android-edittext, android-custom-view, android-textinputlayout, material-components

I'm trying to customize my TextInputLayout to make it like this:
[image]

[image]

[image]

I already tried lots of things using xml attributes but with *style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"* but no success, the hint is always at border level with that space(like the default material).

It's possible to achieve this layout only using the TextInputLayout attributes or I'll have to create a custom view? If so, how would I control the hint animation?